# How to create list from long data in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I have a table like so

| orderId | productId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 |
| 1 | 24 |
| 1 | 27 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 2 | 26 |
| 3 | 27 |

and want to transform it into

| orderId | productIds |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 23,24,27 |
| 2 | 25,26 |
| 3 | 27 |

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
SELECT orderId, STRING_AGG(productId ORDER BY productId) AS productIds
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY orderId;
```